# Update mysql table with multiple arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm attempting to finalise a variation price update routine I've been working on for a few days. I'm still very new PHP.

I'm stuck on the final update sequence. I'm not receiving any errors; but nothing is being updated - presumably because the SQL query is returning 0 values.

Any help massively appreciated. I'm sure it's something simple.

DESIRED RESULT: _price is updated in wp_postmeta for the initially retrieved the post_id record with the _price acquired from the post_parent record. Looped for all the records in the array.

EXAMPLE DATA FROM FINAL DISPLAY OF RETRIVED DATA:

$postids (721, 735, 749, 807)

$parentids (714, 740, 742, 815)

$prices (11.04, 6.32 , 7.69, 21.00)

In an ideal world I'd also like to include a formula to multiply the _price by 2.1 prior/during to insertion/update.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//Select all POST_IDs for variation 2.1M
$sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '2-1m'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//Array and display POST_IDs
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["post_id"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
//Prepare POST_IDs for next query
$postids = [];
foreach ($result as $row){
    $postids[] = $row["post_id"];
}


//Use POST_IDs to select all PARENT_IDs
if (!empty($postids)) {
$sql2 = "SELECT post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (".implode(',',$postids).")";
}
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
//Array and display PARENT_IDs
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "parentid: " . $row2["post_parent"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
//Prepare PARENT_IDs for next query
$parentids = [];
foreach ($result2 as $row2){
    $parentids[] = $row2["post_parent"];
}
//Select PRICES using PARENT_IDs and META_KEY for Price
if (!empty($parentids)) {
$sql3 = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_price' AND post_id IN (".implode(',', $parentids).")";
}
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "price: " . $row3["meta_value"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
//Array and display PRICES
$prices = [];
foreach ($result3 as $row3){
    $prices[] = $row3["meta_value"];
}
//Display all retrieved data
echo "<div><p><table><tr><td> ".implode('<br>', $postids)." </td><td> ".implode('<br>', $parentids)." </td><td> ".implode('<br>', $prices)." </td></tr></table></p></div>";
//UPDATE variant prices with parent prices
foreach ($prices as $key => $postids){
    $prices = $row3["meta_value"];
    $postids = $row["post_id"];
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = $prices WHERE post_id = $key AND meta_key = '_price'";
$update = $conn->query($sqlupdate);
     if (!$sqlupdate)  {
        echo "error updating $prices" . mysql_error();
     }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: In your `UPDATE` statement, you're using `$prices` and `$postids`, which are both arrays. That cannot work, you need to establish a key/value correspondance between these two arrays, and use a loop for your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: One day, in a galaxy far, far away, all human beings would use [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to trap their errors.

Comment: @roberto06 thanks for the feedback. I've updated my code... I'm clearly still way off. I've been staring at this for too long. Any further guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple solution in the end. As I said in the question, I am a PHP beginner. A bit of further understanding RE arrays was required on my part. This is the final query if anyone is interested.

```
//UPDATE variant prices with parent prices
foreach ($prices as $key => $np){
    $pid = $postids["$key"];
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE wp_postmeta 
                    SET meta_value = $np
                    WHERE post_id = $pid 
                    AND meta_key = '_price'";
    $update = $conn->query($sqlupdate);
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdate)){
        echo "Records were updated successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Was not able to execute $sqlupdate. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to consume ALL your query result set's twice. 
Once a query result set is consumed by a while loop it is like getting to the end of a file, it is finished

Merge all 3 of the 2 loops you are using into one loop that outputs and creates the array at the same time. Like this

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Select all POST_IDs for variation 2.1M
$sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '2-1m'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Array and display POST_IDs

$postids = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    // and save in array for later use

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $postids[] = $row["post_id"];
        echo "id: " . $row["post_id"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
/*
No longer needed
//Prepare POST_IDs for next query
foreach ($result as $row){
    $postids[] = $row["post_id"];
}
*/

//Use POST_IDs to select all PARENT_IDs
if (!empty($postids)) {
    $sql2 = "SELECT post_parent 
            FROM wp_posts 
            WHERE ID IN (".implode(',',$postids).")";
}

$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

//Array and display PARENT_IDs
$parentids = [];
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $parentids[] = $row2["post_parent"];
        echo "parentid: " . $row2["post_parent"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

//Select PRICES using PARENT_IDs and META_KEY for Price
if (!empty($parentids)) {
    $sql3 = "SELECT meta_value 
                    FROM wp_postmeta 
                    WHERE meta_key = '_price' 
                    AND post_id IN (".implode(',', $parentids).")";
}

$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);

$prices = [];
if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
        $prices[] = $row3["meta_value"];
        echo "price: " . $row3["meta_value"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

//Display all retrieved data
echo "<div><p><table><tr><td> ".implode('<br>', $postids)." </td><td> ".implode('<br>', $parentids)." </td><td> ".implode('<br>', $prices)." </td></tr></table></p></div>";
```

And here you are overwriting the $prices array that your loop creates inside your loop. And using a `$row3` resultset that no longer exists!

I am afraid I am not at all sure about the data so this last bit of code chnage is a bit of a guess.

```
//UPDATE variant prices with parent prices
foreach ($prices as $key => $postids){

    //$prices = $row3["meta_value"];
    $price = $postids

    //$postids = $row["post_id"];

    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE wp_postmeta 
                    SET meta_value = $price 
                    WHERE post_id = $key 
                    AND meta_key = '_price'";
    $update = $conn->query($sqlupdate);
    if (!$sqlupdate)  {
        echo "error updating $prices" . mysql_error();
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Your recommendations on the data retrieval are all great. Thanks. The final update loop is still where I am stuck and I don't understand your recommendations. The display all retrieved data will output 149 rows that look like 721  715  12.04. In this instance I need to SET meta_value 12.04 WHERE post_id = 721 AND meta_key = '_price'.

Comment: Maybe an example of the `$prices` array might help me get my head around it

Comment: Woops I just spotted a typo in the last loop variable names. Check it again

Comment: I spotted the $price(s) typo. Added further example of the array to the question.

Comment: Now added to main question. Had formatting issues. Sigh.

Comment: Thank you for your help tidying up the first queries. This is resolved with my posted answer. You were a great help. Cheers to you, sir.